# Reason for the experiment

Tags: waves

Why is the independent confirmation  by separate experiments such as important part of the development of the idea of the existence of electron wave?

Comment: Eh?? For the same reason it is important for *every other piece of scientific knowledge*...

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear. [Here i](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment)s the experimental confirmation of the electron-probability-wave.

[image: double slit]

> Electron build up over time

The concept of probability can be measured only statistically. This is true for classical probabilities as well as quantum mechanical ones. The sequantial experiments, one electron at a time, show that an electron approaching the two slits does not go randomly through one or the other (and certainly not from both), but there exists a correlation in space which shows a wave like interference, it is more probable to hit the screen in some regions and less in others, just like classical waves in water. Except this is in probability functions. The probability functions depend on the boundary conditions of the problem.

If one does not repeat the experiment, throwing the electrons at the screen sequentially, one cannot have confirmation, because each individual throw, looks random.